# Libraries API not working in my module

Tags: 8, theming

I'm writing a module that will call some external php libraries. When I was searching for a way to import the library I found the Libraries API. After reading some documentation about the module and core features I found some example code.

When I implement it in my module nothing happens.
My movies.module file contains:

```
/**
* Implements hook_libraries_info()
**/
function movies_libraries_info()
{

  // This array key lets Libraries API search for 'sites/all/libraries/example'
  // directory, which should contain the entire, original extracted library.
  $libraries['imdb'] = array(
    // Only used in administrative UI of Libraries API.
    'name' => 'imdb', 
    'vendor url' => 'https://github.com/tboothman/imdbphp', 
    'download url' => 'https://github.com/tboothman/imdbphp/releases',
     // Default list of files of the library to load. Important: Only specify
    // third-party files belonging to the library here, not integration files of
    // your module. 
    'files' => array(
      // For PHP libraries, specify include files here, still relative to the
      // library path. 
      'php' => array(
        'bootstrap.php',
      ),
    ),
    // Optional: Register files to auto-load for your module. All files must be
    // keyed by module, and follow the syntax of the 'files' property. 
    'integration files' => array(
      'movies' => array(
        'php' => array('bootstrap.php'),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

No errors are thrown when enabling my module when the library is not installed.

How can my module load the external PHP library using the Libraries APi?

Comment: Page does not exist on my Drupal 8 instance with Libraries Module enabled

Comment: Don't use libraries for PHP dependencies, use composer: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-with-drupal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a `composer.json` file to your `movies` module & name it your custom module's name:

   ```
   {
     "name": "drupal/movies",
     "type": "drupal-module",
     "license": "GPL-2.0+",
     "require": {
       "imdbphp/imdbphp": "*"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add a new line to the merge-plugin include array in the `composer.json` of your Drupal ROOT with your module's composer file path:

   ```
   "extra": {
     "merge-plugin": {
       "include": [
           "core/composer.json",
           "modules/custom/movies/composer.json"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. Enable the `movies` module
4. Run `composer update` & `composer dumpauto` in Drupal ROOT. This will install & autoload the new dependencies in your vendor directory.
5. Now you can use the classes provided by this library. In your case for example:

   ```
   $title = new \Imdb\Title(335266);
   ```

Comment: Is this the recommended method for installing a CSS library, too?

Answer (score -3):

You can load libraries from the Libaries API in Drupal 7 in two ways:

1) You can use the function [libraries_load()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_load/7)

2) You can use the #attached method of a render array as follows:

```
$form['myelement']['#attached']['libraries_load'][] = array('my_library');
```

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8 and nog Drupal 7.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The D8 version doesn't even have a release yet, there's only a dev version. It won't be usable.

Comment: Hey @Jaypan, this answer looks like a perfect opportunity to use it for gaining [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge ... wanna try?