# How do I include a CSS library in my custom module?

Tags: 8, composer, theming

I want to include the YAMM!3 CSS library in my Drupal 8 site. To that end, I wrote a custom module following the instructions in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224911/1441). Although that answer is in regards to a php library, I thought it would also work for a CSS library.

This is the `composer.json` from my custom module:

```
{
  "name": "drupal/my_yamm3",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "require": {
    "geedmo/yamm3": "*"
  }
}
```

In the `composer.json` in the root of my Drupal codebase, I have this:

```
"extra": {
    ...
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json",
            "modules/custom/my_yamm3/composer.json"
        ],
    ...
```

I updated my codebase with this commands:

```
$ composer update
$ composer dumpauto
```

And I noticed this line in composer's output:

```
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
  - Installing geedmo/yamm3 (1.1.0): Loading from cache
```

Which is confirmed by an examination of the filesystem:

```
$ ls vendor/geedmo/yamm3/
bower.json  composer.json  demo/  gulpfile.js  index.html  LICENSE.txt  package.json  README.md  yamm/
```

I've enabled the `my_yamm3` module on my site, and under `admin/config/development/performance`, I've disabled css aggregation.

However, when I load the page, I do not see the yamm libraries being loaded in the network tab in my browser.

Am I using the correct method to load a third-party css library? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** osman asked for some confirmation of the state of my environment. In my drupal project root, while I do have `/composer.json` and the directories `/drush/` and `/vendor/`, I don't have `/scripts/` nor `/web/`. I guess that means I am not using the `drupal-composer/drupal-project` project.

Regarding his recommended additions to `composer.json`, this is what I had:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    }
},
```

So again it looks like I don't have the composer project?

Comment: You were already on the right way. `composer-merge-plugin` plus `custom-installer`. Then you define a location for third party theme libs like for example `web/themes/custom/MYTHEME/libs/{$name}`. And in your custom module's `composer.json` you reference the library directly from GitHub tagging it with the `custom-installer` type defined before. See step-by-step https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260766/15055

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, now I see your main problem actually is that all you've forgotten is to bind the lib from `MYMODULE.libraries.yml` and then simply attach it to every page with `hook_page_attachments` from within `MYMODULE.module`. See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).

Answer (score 3):

**Fundamentals**

To bind a CSS library into your Drupal installation, it should be defined and exposed via a *.libraries.yaml file.

For example (taken from core's classy theme):

```
book-navigation:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    component:
      css/components/book-navigation.css: {}
```

defines that there is a library called `book-navigation` that when included in a page will deliver the `css/components/book-navigation.css` css file.

**Using composer with 3rd-party CSS libraries**

Composer works easily and reliably for PHP dependencies, using the `merge-plugin` in the way you started working in the OP. But, CSS and Javascript libraries, especially when some preprocessing or building step is required, are a different story.
This is an open and unsolved (to my knowledge and to the date) problem, you can read this issue to get an idea of what problems arise:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2873160

The main problem is, that when you import the library as a composer dependency, as you did, the library is installed inside the `vendor` directory **wherever** that is located. So, you cannot assume much inside your *libraries.yaml file about the file path to the CSS/JS file(s) you want to use.

**Alternative (A) without composer: using CDN / externally hosted libraries definitions**

For you case, and taken that you want to include this file:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geedmo/yamm3/master/yamm/yamm.css
```

you could define it inside your *libraries.yaml file as an externally hosted library (see [#external](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#external)):

```
my_module.yamm3:
  remote:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geedmo/yamm3/master/yamm/yamm.css
  version: VERSION
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/geedmo/yamm3/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  css:
    theme:
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geedmo/yamm3/master/yamm/yamm.css : { type: external }
```

N.B.: This approach should always deliver the latest `yamm.css` version.

**Alternative (B) without composer: keeping a local copy in your own module's folder**

If you place the CSS file inside your module's folder, e.g. `css/yamm.css`, you will be able to use the following yaml definition in your *.libraries.yaml file in order to be able to use it:

```
my_module.yamm3:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/yamm.css : {}
```

**Attaching a library to page(s)**

Finally, after you are done defining your library, you can start using it.

This is documented extensively here (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) and I would recommend reading that if you haven't already.

Good luck!

Comment: for Alt. B, is one of the `css` lines supposed to be the name of my current theme? I used `hook_page_attachments_alter` and I'm getting this `User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: css in drupal_get_filename() (line 268 of core\includes\bootstrap.inc).

drupal_get_filename('theme', 'css') (Line: 291)
drupal_get_path('theme', 'css') (Line: 394)
...
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName('css', 'yamm.css') (Line: 54) ...`

Comment: Nope, this approach is theme independent. Can you give an example of how you call `hook_page_attachments_alter`?

Comment: Looke like this: `function my_yamm3_page_attachments_alter(&$build) {
  $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'css/yamm.css';
}`

Comment: That should be `$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.yamm3';`: you need to use the machine name of the module and the library, not the filepaths or filenames. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#pages

Answer (score 1):

More likely your `vendor` directory is off of the web root. Could you confirm that?

If you by any chance using `drupal-composer/drupal-project` project, it would have a folder structure like this:

```
/composer.json
/drush/
/scripts/
/vendor/
/web/
/web/core/
/web/libraries/
/web/modules/
/web/profiles/
/web/sites/
/web/themes/
...
```

The `libraries` folder is the folder you need your [YAMM!3 CSS](https://github.com/geedmo/yamm3) library placed in. So that it could be accessible via web also.

In my `composer.json` file I have Drupal specific folders defined in `extra.installer-paths`:

```
...
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
    }
}
```

With the help of `composer/installers` package and the configuration in `extra`, each package required by composer is copied to their own dedicated folders. So, yours could be copied into `libraries` folder.

Check out the code and documentation at https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

It should provide all the details for you to update your project to support what you need. Otherwise come back for more :)

Comment: I made an update to my question, from what I understand, it looks like I don't have the drupal-composer project. Is that necessary for this to work? Is there another way to install a CSS library?

Comment: Hi user1359, is the real issue not being able to install YAMM!3 CSS library via composer, or once installed not being able to load the library on required pages?

Comment: of course, my ultimate goal is to get the YAMM!3 library loaded. How I do that, I don't really care. I googled how to do that, and found the instructions that I linked, and the only way I can tell whether it worked or not is if the library loads or fails to load. I am not aware of any other way to test that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Loading a (CSS or JS) library would easily be done via implementing `hook_page_attachments()` hook. This could be done more easily if you define a `yourmodule.libraries.yml` file for the YAMM!3 library. @Stefanos Petrakis's answer covers that part. And my answer was focusing on how to define an external Composer package as a dependency and install it as a library item.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write out this very detailed answer and help me understand my situation : )

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 does not allow for an easy way to set up libraries that use files in the vendor directory. To get around this, I just created the [Vendor Stream Wrapper module](http://dgo.to/vendor_stream_wrapper), which creates a vendor:// stream wrapper, allowing for linking to files in the vendor folder, even if it is outside the webroot.